# Most efficient way to retrieve ~100MB query result size in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using `jobs.query` has the limitation of `10MB` byteSize, and so I have to pagination/request 10 times in order to retrieve `100MB` data in BigQuery.

I am looking for how to run a query and download about the result (~100MB) in the fastest possible time. What would be the suggested way to do this?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

Additionally, is there a way to retrieve the query result in a compressed format (if that would speed things up at all?)

Comment: Where do you need to get the final result/file to e.g. locally?

Comment: @GrahamPolley -- yes, locally. But it would probably be fed into javascript/browser, so either a gcs storage link of the results, or serve the data from an http request. I'll probably benchmark both of Felipe's solutions and see which works better for our case.

Comment: I created a feature request you can upvote to get a CLI tool to download. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133442769

Comment: @FelipeHoffa -- awesome, thank you! I would say a table or query (though I believe the query saves to a tmp table anyways, so may be a moot point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

1. Run an export job. Specify gzip compression. Load the file from GCS.
2. Use the new [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/).

I created a feature request you can upvote to get a CLI tool to download with the Storage API:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133442769

Comment: thanks, in your experience which of the above seems to be "faster" when retrieving relatively large querysets?

Comment: 1. is the current fastest. 2. is the newest fastest (and indeed faster), but still in beta.